# How do I create valid JSON from database rows

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I don’t know how to wirte the PHP to go with my JSON JavaScript code. I assume I need it to parse each row into a main array that assigns each one a unique value key starting with 1 to infinity. However, honestly I’ve looked and I don’t get how to do it. Also, if you see anything wrong with the mapping adding marker, please let me know.

PHP CODE:

```
 <?php
 include 'dbconnect.php';

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coords ORDER BY name DESC") or die ("Could 
 not query");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $r[] = array(
  "name" => $row['name'],
  "lat" => $row['lat'],
  "lng" => $row['lng'],
  "speed" => $row['speed'],
  "altitude" => $row['altitude'],
   "distance" => $row['distance']
);
}

$encoded = json_encode($r);
echo $encoded;

exit($encoded);

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
  var usermarker;
    var markloc;

    function deleteUserOverlay() {
        if (usermarker) {
            usermarker.setMap(null);
        }
    }

    function calluserlocation(){
     console.log('calluserlocation fires');
$.ajax( { 
url: "getdata.php",
type: "GET", 
dataType: "json", 
success: function(data) { for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { markloc = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].b, data[i].c); adddata(markloc); } }, error: function(data) { console.log( "error" ); } });
console.log("sucessful run of function");

}
   function adddata(markloc){ 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markloc,
     icon: 'http://www.wolfdoginfo.net/app/cropcircles.png',
    map: map
  });
deleteUserOverlay();
usermarker = marker;  
   }
```

I get errors in the console and my dad now outputs like this

[{"name":"test2","lat":"39.8441792","lng":"-105.104921","speed":"bad","altitude":"dontcare","distance":"whatever"},{"name":"test","lat":"39.729431999999996","lng":"-104.831919","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"grant3","lat":"39.729431999999996","lng":"-104.831919","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"grant2","lat":"test34","lng":"test34","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"grant","lat":"39.729431999999996","lng":"-104.831919","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"","lat":"39.75198511","lng":"-104.85021166","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"}][{"name":"test2","lat":"39.8441792","lng":"-105.104921","speed":"bad","altitude":"dontcare","distance":"whatever"},{"name":"test","lat":"39.729431999999996","lng":"-104.831919","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"grant3","lat":"39.729431999999996","lng":"-104.831919","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"grant2","lat":"test34","lng":"test34","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"grant","lat":"39.729431999999996","lng":"-104.831919","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"},{"name":"","lat":"39.75198511","lng":"-104.85021166","speed":"speed","altitude":"altitude","distance":"distance"}]

so now my php is outputting correctly just twice for somereason
but my json code isnt working. I need to populate the marker for each entry.

consays:

```
[01:57:52.768] GET http://wolfdoginfo.net/app/show/getdata.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 86ms]
[01:57:52.705] "calluserlocation fires"
[01:57:52.705] "sucessful run of function"
[01:57:52.826] "error"
```

Comment: You should consider using the MySQLi extension as mysql_* is deprecated since PHP 5.5

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your PHP code is returning invalid JSON, because it is a series of json strings, instead of one combined array.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo json_encode(array( "a" => $row['name'], "b" => $row['lat'], "c" => $row['lng'], "d" => $row['speed'], "e" => $row['altitude'], "f" => $row['distance']));
}
// this code will return this JSON
// { a:?, b:?, c:?, ... }
// { a:?, b:?, c:?, ... }
// ...
```

You should combine them into one array and return it.

```
$return = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $return [] = array( "a" => $row['name'], "b" => $row['lat'], "c" => $row['lng'], "d" => $row['speed'], "e" => $row['altitude'], "f" => $row['distance']));
}
echo json_encode($return);
// this code will return
// [
//    { a:?, b:?, c:?, ... },
//    { a:?, b:?, c:?, ... },
//    ...
// ]
```

Which is an array of objects, instead of just loose objects.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should push all the details into an array and then after encode that array in to json string. You can achieve that by using code like :

```
$details_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
array_push($details_array, $row);//pushes all the fetched row data into $details_array
}
echo json_encode($details_array);
```

Comment: <?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coords ORDER BY name DESC") or die ("Could not query");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 
    $r[] = array(
 "name" => $row['name'],
   "lat" => $row['lat'],
      "lng" => $row['lng'],
      "speed" => $row['speed'],
      "altitude" => $row['altitude'],
    "distance" => $row['distance']
    );
  }
  
$encoded = json_encode($r);
echo $encoded;

exit($encoded);

mysql_close($conn);

?>

Comment: I udated can you look again please